# Why can't I define a variable inside a definition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a countdown going, and I can't define a variable or pull a var from outside.

This is my variable.

```
go = True
```

This is the countdown.

```
def countdown(n):
while n > 0:
    print(n)
    time.sleep(1)
    n = n - 1
    if n == 0:
        print("The storm has taken you!")
        retry = input("Would you like to play again?")
        if retry == "yes" or "Yes":
```

This is where the problem occurs, as the system says "Shadows name 'go' from outer scope" and "Local variable 'go' is not used."

```
            go = True
```

The variable 'go' is being used for:

```
while go: # Beginning script!
    print("Welcome to 'Adventures into ZORK!'")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Entering ZORK! in three...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("two...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("one...")
    time.sleep(1)
    go = False
```

Comment: What are you using `go` for?

Comment: Added it to the question @Alex

Comment: You have to `go` variables: one global and one local. That is perfectly fine. You are just getting a warning that the global `go` will not be visible in the function. The warning does not even come from Python, but from your IDE (e.g. PyCharm). To avoid that, don't use global variables at all - put the  `while` loop and the global `go` into a separate function, let's call it `main()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the variable to the definition

```
def countdown(n,go):
  while n > 0:
    print(n)
    time.sleep(1)
    n = n - 1
    if n == 0:
      print("The storm has taken you!")
      retry = input("Would you like to play again?")
      if retry == "yes" or "Yes":
```

Then pass the variable like

```
countdown(0,go)
```

**EDIT:**

```
if retry == "yes" or "Yes":
```

could rather be:

```
if retry.upper() == "YES" or retry.upper() == "Y":
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `go = True` with

```
global go
go = True
```

This way go will be visible inside the function. Or better, just put `global go` at the beginning of your function. Or even better, just define go in the function, if it is not being used anywhere else.

Comment: So it worked fine, but it's not executing my while loop.

Comment: Is the while loop inside or outside the function?

Comment: Outside @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000